# How to use the alt/option key as the "meta" key in NetBeans on OS X with emacs keybindings?

Tags: macos, emacs, netbeans, key-bindings

NetBeans supports emacs-style keybindings, but for some reason it uses cmd as the "meta" key instead of alt, which seems to be the standard on OS X.  (Terminal.app has a checkbox for "use option as meta key", for example.)  How can I switch to using alt/option as the "meta" key for emacs-style keybindings?

Answer (score 0):

Not too long ago I'd export, edit and import an xml file using the keymap panel in preferences.

Now I'd do some file renaming in ~/.netbeans/6.7/config/Keymaps/*profile*

The Netbeans Key Codes seem to be:

```
 In 2008     NB 6.7.1     PC       Mac   
    D           M        Meta    command 
    S           S        Shift   shift   
    O           C        Ctrl    control 
    A           A        Alt     option
```

Comment: Those files somehow represent keybindings?  There don't seem to be enough of them.  Also, what do I do?  The files have names like A-W.shadow_hidden D-6.shadow   DS-F.shadow    OS-D.shadow, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can go to
~/.netbeans/6.*/config/Editors/Keybings/profilename

And its a big XML file that you can edit.

Also despite his list up above, I see this in most commands.

```
A - option (alt)
D - command (meta)
S - Shift
O - Control
```

I was able to happily assign commands to use option.

Comment: But that seems to require editing *every* command. It'd be nice to just do a mass switch, since the keybindings are systematically backwards.